# Why do my tensorflow graph weights and biases not change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

the following code runs, but when I print each weight and bias tensors, the fields in it are all zero. I know, I initialized them with zeros, but why doesn't the optimizer work as I expected? Therefore the cost function doesn't change, too. What's the missunderstanding?

Here The Code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5], name='input')

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b) 


y_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1],     name='output')
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_tensor 
* tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

optimizer = 
 tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)


session = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session.run(init)

for i in range(10):
  batch_xs = [dataA[i], dataB[i], dataC[i], dataD[i],
          dataE[i]]]
  batch_ys = [[dataG[i]]]
  session.run(optimizer ,feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_tensor: batch_ys})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the mistake. The batches are initialized again in every iteraion in the for loop. This causes an array wich does not contain my complete dataset. It contains only 1 field with the given data. So the optimizer can not optize, because the loss funktion consits of only one data field, equivalent to a one dimensional funktion with only on pair of x and y. This funktion has no gradient, because it is a single point! The problem should be solved, when I cut this peace of code

```
 batch_xs = [dataA[i], dataB[i], dataC[i], dataD[i],
          dataE[i]]]
 batch_ys = [[dataG[i]]]
```

and put it the right way outside the for loop to initialize the batches correctly.